# Determine the truth value of each proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So I'm working on this assignment but I'm not really sure how to get the value of $x$. I'm confused in getting the value of $x$. I just want to know how to get it so I can determine the truth value of it.

> Let $P(x)$ be the statement $x^3+5x\le6$. Determine the truth value of each proposition:
>
> 1. $P(0)$
> 2. …

I didn't put all the problems since I just want to know how to get that value, not the answer directly.

Comment: replace $x$ by $0$ in the expression $x^3 + 5x \le 6$ and check it. Is $0^3+5\times 0 \le 6$ ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you :D :D  ....

Answer (score 1):

Put 0 (zero) for $x$ and you will get that $0 \leq 6$ (true).